# How to Parse Json Data to html in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, web-services

I am calling a webservice which is returned json data (Using Json.net for jsonSerialize). I want to retrieve that data via Jquery.

Json data is:

```
{
  "DTItems":[
    {
      "ItemsId":23132,
      "Selection":"123",
      "Item1":5.0,
      "Item2":1000.000000,
      "Item3":0.0,
      "Item4":0.000000,
      "Item5":0.0,
      "item6":0.000000,
      "item7":1.0,
      "item8":1000.000000,
      "item9":0.0,
      "item10":0.000000,
      "item11":0.0,
      "item12":0.000000,
      "Allowed":false
    },
    {
      "ItemsId":23132,
      "Selection":"123",
      "Item1":5.0,
      "Item2":1000.000000,
      "Item3":0.0,
      "Item4":0.000000,
      "Item5":0.0,
      "item6":0.000000,
      "item7":1.0,
      "item8":1000.000000,
      "item9":0.0,
      "item10":0.000000,
      "item11":0.0,
      "item12":0.000000,
      "Allowed":false
    },
    {
      "ItemsId":23132,
      "Selection":"123",
      "Item1":5.0,
      "Item2":1000.000000,
      "Item3":0.0,
      "Item4":0.000000,
      "Item5":0.0,
      "item6":0.000000,
      "item7":1.0,
      "item8":1000.000000,
      "item9":0.0,
      "item10":0.000000,
      "item11":0.0,
      "item12":0.000000,
      "Allowed":false
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to assign each item to each variable. Please Help me.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td>item2</td>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>item4</td>
        <td>item5</td>
        <td>item6</td>
        <td>item7</td>
        <td>item8</td>
        <td>item10</td>
        <td>item11</td>
        <td>item12</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

like that

Comment: Can you please post an example of the HTML you'd like to see?

Comment: I want to add it in Html Table.

Comment: Please post a mock-up table which shows the desired result.

Comment: i edited this post please check now

Comment: So you want a table with one row which contains only cells with the text “itemX”?

Comment: Yes i want cells with the text of itemX but row counts varies on how many rows Json has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegExp is pretty helpful in such case. Check this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6vh1k6f/7/)

#### HTML

```html
<div id="div1">
...content here
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
    var json = ...your json...

    for (var i = 0; i < json["DTItems"].length; i++) {
    var obj = json["DTItems"][i];
    var $table = $('<table>', {});
    var $tr = $('<tr>', {});
    $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
        // /Item\d+|item\d+/ = every Item or item followed by digits
        if (index.toString().match(/Item\d+|item\d+/) !== null) {

            var $td = $('<td>', {
                html: value
            });
            $($td).appendTo($tr);

        }
    });
    $($tr).appendTo($table);
    $($table).appendTo("#div1");
}
```